# How many punctuation marks are there?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Most websites say that there are 14 punctuation marks, for example '[Punctuation Marks in English Grammar](https://eklavyaparv.com/content/communication-skills/362-punctuation-marks-in-english-grammar#:%7E:text=Broadly%20speaking%2C%20there%20are%2014,%2C%20quotation%20marks%2C%20and%20ellipses.)' or '[What Are the 14 Punctuation Marks in English Grammar?](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/what/fourteen-punctuation-marks.html)'

However, I feel like there are more punctuation marks, for instance '[How to use punctuation marks](https://www.gkbledsoe.com/how-to-use-punctuation-marks/)'. This website shows 16 punctuation marks?

Which one is right? Which one should I trust? How many punctuation marks are there?

Comment: Who says I cannot invent my own punctuation♡  My iPhone is loaded with emojis 

Comment: Are emojis punctuations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard list of punctuation marks. They are designed by and for printers, not writers, and every publisher has their own set of punctuation marks, and a style manual for their use. It's been this way since printing was invented, and has never stabilized, even in (or perhaps especially in) English. So don't bother counting; somebody else could count different.

As I put it in [this encyclopedia article](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf),

> **Punctuation** refers to various systems of dots (Lat *punctus*) and other marks that accompany letters and other glyphs as part of a writing system. Although there is a certain overlap among the various kinds of markings, punctuation proper should be distinguished from **diacritic marks**, which are intended as modifications of individual letters (e.g, **ö ő å í è ç š ơ ū ñ ṇ**) and are often simply considered to be part of the letter they appear on, like the dot on the Latin lower-case *i*. Punctuation marks are distinguished as well as from logographs, which are simply one-glyph representations of lexical items (e.g, **@ # $ % &**).
>
> Several other common glyphs, like the slash indicating alternation (*and/or*), or asterisk ‘ * ’ indicating some special qualification like a footnote or ungrammaticality, are intermediate between these categories, but are not considered true punctuation. This article will consider only punctuation marks that appear separately from other written glyphs and have no lexicalreference.
>
> The modern suite of punctuation marks includes the period ‘**.**’, comma ‘ **,** ’, colon ‘ **:** ’,
> semicolon ‘ **;** ’, left and right parentheses ‘ **( )** ’ (and other brackets, square ‘ **[ ]** ’, angle ‘ **< >** ’, and curly ‘ **{ }** ’), interrogation and exclamation marks ‘ **? !** ’ (bracketed with their inverses ‘ **¿ ¡** ’ in
> Spanish), dashes of several lengths ‘ **- – —** ’, single and double quotation marks **‘ “ « » ” ’**, and the apostrophe, or raised comma “ **’** ” (not to be confused with the prime mark ‘ **′** ’, which is a diacritic).

Comment: The once Waldorf=Astoria (hotel) apparently started life as the Waldorf-Astoria; the use of the double hyphen, indeed any hyphen, was discontinued by parent company Hilton as recently as 2009.

Comment: "There is no standard list of punctuation marks" why do most websites and especially this one (https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/what/fourteen-punctuation-marks.html) claims that there are 14 punctuation marks by says the fourteen punctuations in English grammar?

Comment: Because anybody can say anything they want to about English on the net, and somebody will believe it, and copy it, and charge for it. And somebody else will do the same. As you will have noticed by now, most stuff you find on the net about English is bullshit, or incomprehensible, or both.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you so much I really appreciate your answer. what does "charge for it" mean? and yes most of it is just bullshit and I am more and more confused everyday to be honest so is there a way I can learn about English while avoiding those bullshits?

Comment: @pobig43001 Hang out with native speakers and copy their usage. Read all the time. Try to think of alternative ways to say things and try them out. Don't be afraid to make mistakes but try to recognize them and not repeat them. Don't write until you can speak well; you need something good to say before you try writing. Writing is **much** harder than speaking, whatever they tell you, and the easiest way to write is to write like you talk; but you hafta have something worth saying first.

Comment: " Read all the time." if most of the stuff I find on the net about English is bullshit then what should I read? also what does "charge for it" in your previous comment means?

Comment: "Charge for it" means they will put the bs in textbooks and sell them. If your headmaster isn't an English language specialist, they're likely to buy whatever's cheap. As I said, anybody can say anything and somebody will believe them. Don't read on the internet -- unless you are reading books. There are millions of good books on the net; download them (they take up far less room than movies or games) and read them. Histories, biographies, novels, comics, anything. But not online grammar advice; learn linguistics to protect against that.

Answer (score 1):

So the fourteen are "period, question mark, exclamation point, comma, semicolon, colon, dash, hyphen, parentheses, brackets, braces, apostrophe, quotation marks, and ellipsis" — it's interesting that both your sources list them in the same order — and the list of sixteen separates single-quotes from double-quotes and adds the asterisk.

Your [first reference](https://eklavyaparv.com/content/communication-skills/362-punctuation-marks-in-english-grammar#:%7E:text=Broadly%20speaking%2C%20there%20are%2014,%2C%20quotation%20marks%2C%20and%20ellipses.) says "it is Punctuation [sic] actually which transforms our words into standard and correct structure-syntax or sentences", and by that norm, the asterisk is not a *punctuation* mark. It's a reference marker. The [third reference](https://www.gkbledsoe.com/how-to-use-punctuation-marks/) doesn't actually explain why they include the asterisk, anyway.

If you're going to count the asterisk as punctuation, then you have to include all such marks, like the dagger †, double-dagger ‡, and various paragraph marks which can be used (§ and ¶). You might even include counted references like ¹, ², ³; and I've even seen a double vertical bar ‖ and a crossed double vertical bar. But those marks don't have anything to do with correct structure and syntax.

I would go so far as to group parentheses and brackets, since they have the same function; to group single- and double-quotes, since they have the same function too; to leave out braces which have no function (but if they do, then it's purely parenthetical like brackets); and to leave out anything which does not contribute to sentence structure and syntax, like the asterisk.

So **my** list would be period, question mark, exclamation mark, comma, semicolon, colon, dash, hyphen, parenthetical marks, apostrophe, quotation marks, and ellipsis. That's twelve.

Comment: I would go so far as to group parentheses and brackets. The separation can be useful: parentheses for additional information; brackets for explanatory remarks - https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-quotation-marks/uses-of-parentheses

Comment: Even explanatory remarks are parenthetical. Although using brackets for editorial replacement in a quote might be enough to separate them.

Comment: What about the interobang?!  I also wonder why the slash is excluded/forgotten. In addition, I've seen a proposed sarcasm/irony punctuation mark, but it looks like a script Hebrew peh to me. `\-()-/'